# Concatenate with Memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy, memset

I'm trying to concatenate two string and I cannot use strcpy and strcat, so I'm trying to do this through memcopy. However, on the third statement the memcpy it is not adding on to the continuation of the first memcpy. Any idea how to do this?

```
memset(&l->db.param_key.param_name, ' ', sizeof(l->db.param_key.param_name));
memcpy(l->db.param_key.param_name,g->program_id_DB,(strlen(g->program_id_DB)));
memcpy(l->db.param_key.param_name[strlen(g->program_id_DB)+1],l->userId_const,sizeof(l->userId_const));
```

Comment: Why can't you use `strcpy` or `strcat`?

Comment: Are you aware, that `&l->...` within memset will lead to overwriting the pointer to the string you want to edit? Leave out the `&`. Also this sounds to me like homework. If so then please tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving to the second memcpy the valye of the last array's element.
The correct way is to give the address(with the ampersand operator (like it was implicitly meant in the second statement).

```
memcpy(&l->db.param_key.param_name[strlen(g->program_id_DB)+1],l->userId_const,sizeof(l->userId_const))
```

Answer (score 1):

The address in the third invocation should be:

```
l->db.param_key.param_name + strlen(g->program_id_DB) + 1
```

Note that for `T * p`,  the expression `p[i];` is identical to `*(p + i)`. You don't want to dereference, you want the address, so you just add to the pointer.

(It is also true that `p + i` is identical to `&p[i]` as long as `i` is a valid index.)

Also mind @Nobody's observation that your first line is incorrect and you should just say `l->db.param_key.param_name` (or equivalently `&l->db.param_key.param_name[0]`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `memcpy()` exactly like `strcpy()` except you have to work with string size instead of string length.

Answer (score 0):

your codeexample is a little bit horrible, but

```
memset(l->db.param_key.param_name,0,sizeof(l->db.param_key.param_name));
memcpy(l->db.param_key.param_name,g->program_id_DB,strlen(g->program_id_DB));
memcpy(&l->db.param_key.param_name[strlen(g->program_id_DB)],l->userId_const,sizeof(l->userId_const));
```

should work, **if** l->db.param_key.param_name and l->userId_const are a char-arrays.